# Runtime errors on using veins and veins_inet content on same simulation

Tags: c++, runtime-error, omnet++, veins

Ubuntu - 20.04 , Omnetpp - 5.5.1 , veins - 5.0 , Sumo - 1.6.0 , Inet - 3.6.7

I'm doing a project where I want to create a DSRC based and wifi based vehicular simulatons in the same simulate environment (same project).

I tried to get RSU and the Car node from veins example to veins_inet example to simulate both there.

```
package org.car2x.veins.subprojects.veins_inet.example;

import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer;
import org.car2x.veins.nodes.RSU;
import org.car2x.veins.subprojects.veins_inet.VeinsInetManager;

network Scenario
{
    submodules:
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
        manager: VeinsInetManager;
        node[0]: Car;
        rsu: RSU {
            @display("p=293,82");
        }
        car: org.car2x.veins.nodes.Car {
            @display("p=139,106");
        }
        connections allowunconnected:
}
```

but it has `runtime errors` constantly.
I edited my `omnetpp.ini` with all empty parameters from NED parameters.

Error:

```
Simulation terminated with exit code: 139
```

How am I supposed to resolve these issues?

How can I change connection manager ?
Is there any doc i can refer into ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the Veins FAQ at http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/faq/ for help on how to debug a simulation, specifically the entry `What happened? My simulation crashed.` and the entry `How can I debug my OMNeT++ simulation models? How do I create a stack trace?` (in brief: run the simulation in debug mode and set `debug-on-errors = true`)